# Can't open android virtual device in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm starting my android virtual device in Android Studio as usual.And the codes is definitely right because i run it the day before yesterday.But today it didn't work as I have updated the emulator first.How to fix it?
My computer is windows 10,the SDK Tools has upgraded to the latest version(Include android emulator).The java version is "1.8.0-211".

[This is the event log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh6Zk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem after a lot of trial and error.

Firstly I changed the build-tools.
After that, Gradle build finished with an aapt error, for which I installed the following.

- sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
- sudo apt-get install lib32z1

These solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.But my computer system is Windows 10,not Ubuntu.

Comment: Try to update your SDK manager tools package. SDKmanager is the command line tool that allows you to view, install, update.is located in android_sdk/tools/bin/.To update all packages sdkmanager --update. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Open `AVD Manager` and wipe device data.

[image: avd manager]

---

Also `File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`. Invalidate and restart.